# Frontend IP listen on HTTP and HTTPS on Google cloud internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing,

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I configure Google cloud **internal** HTTP(S) Load Balancing to listen on HTTP and HTTPS with the same internal frontend IP.

I get this error when trying:
IP 'XX.XX.XX.XX' is already being used by another resource.

note, on external HTTP/S load balancing it works perfect.

Comment: Did you create the IP address at the same time as creating the frontends? Create the IP address first, then create both frontends.

Comment: with both ways I get same results, IP 'XX.XX.XX.XX' is already being used by another resource

Answer (score 2):

You can create more than one frontend for an Internal Load Balancer using different IPs, but you cannot use the same IP for more than one frontend.

As per [Internal l7LB limitations](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal#limitations) “Within each VPC network, each internal managed forwarding rule must have its own IP address.”

See also [this article](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#unique_ip_addresses) to confirm the following:

If the forwarding rule's load balancing scheme is one of the following, it must have a unique IP address:

- INTERNAL for internal TCP/UDP load balancers
- INTERNAL_MANAGED for internal HTTP(S) load balancers
- INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED for Traffic Director

For this specific scenario, I would recommend using this link and report it as a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=1162611).

As a workaround, if you don’t have the requirement of an HTTP LB, you can always use a TCP/UDP Internal Load Balancer, with which you can choose between use up to five different ports for the same IP, or use all ports, details [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/#all_ports)

“An internal forwarding rule that supports either all TCP ports or all UDP ports allows backend VMs to run multiple applications, each on its own port. Traffic sent to a given port is delivered to the corresponding application, and all applications use the same IP address.”

I hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, google did not think it through?

Comment: I agree this is an important feature for an l7LB. I see this has been already reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150198169).