# Error with internal LB for same ip address

Tags: http, networking, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

How to create http internal LB with using same static IPs for http and https front-end . Its giving me error " contact to gcp "

It could be done through external http LB and internal network LB but still in beta.

Any work around would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is " contact to gcp " the exact error you get in the Cloud Console or as an output of the `gcloud` command?

Comment: This is the exact error I get through console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a configuration is unfeasible for the Google Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing yet.

There is a relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60397188/11602913) on Stack Overflow that mentions existing limitations.

[Load Balancing > Doc > Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing overview > Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal#limitations):

> - Within each VPC network, each internal managed forwarding rule must have its own IP address.
> - The internal forwarding rule that your internal HTTP(S) load balancer uses must have exactly one port.

[Load Balancing > Doc > Forwarding rules overview > IP address specifications > Multiple forwarding rules with a common IP address](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#unique_ip_addresses):

> If the forwarding rule's load balancing scheme is one of the
>   following, it must have a unique IP address:
>
> - INTERNAL_MANAGED for internal HTTP(S) load balancers

Also, you may follow an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/150198169) on Issue Tracker that is actually a Feature Request for the Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and detail information, however I found a work around by using internal network LB though the product is not fully GA